# Как ускорить адаптацию сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Сейчас верстаю сайты без сетки, хаком clearfix. Знаю про бутстрап и подобные фреймворки. Но все сайты что я верстаю, они не по сетке, т.е. какая то сетка там есть, но что бы вот так просто использовать сетку бутстрапа и только классы подставлять не получится, нужно все равно все в ручную подправлять.

В чем вопрос. Как ускорить адаптацию сайта? Как я понимаю при нынешних реалиях сайтов четко по сетке мало. Как быть? думаю проще использовать бутстрап сетку на 16 колонок что бы проще было разбивать на блоки, так как сайт не по сетке.

Сложность еще в том что я пишу медиа в том месте где сайт ломается, а в бутстрапе заранее эти точки прописаны, что как бы мне не совсем подходит.

Может создать сетку самому на 24 колонки что бы было проще разбивать? Надоело писать медиа типа если 2 блока было по 50% ширины и теперь нужно в медиа писать что каждый блок по 100% что бы поставить их в ряд и еще кучу других мелочей. Не хочу на адаптации заострять внимание, хочется быстрого практичного решения.

Даже если использовать сетку бутстрап и разбить с помощью классов для разных экранов, все равно придется дописывать в медиа вручную выравнивание текста, удаление ненужных элементов отступы и т.д.

Кто как с этим всем борется и какие можете предложить решения? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы заметили, что Bootstrap [настраивается](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables)? Число колонок, ширина экрана, при которой срабатывают правила media-query – всё рулится.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам будет интересно почитать о [CSS Flexible Box Layout](https://medium.com/@Heydon/flexbox-grid-finesse-4d22b80bfee1#.klohni7qf), который уже [поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) последними версиями браузеров, и реализовывать сетку без bootstrap`а

Answer (score -1):

Ну почему бы не написать свою сетку на каком нибудь препроцессоре и легко ее кастомить от проекта к проекту. Ну либо воспользоваться каким нибудь генератором которых очень много на просторах.
[gridcalculator.dk](http://gridcalculator.dk/)
[gridpak.com/](http://gridpak.com/)...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?